# Login screen corruption

Tags: unity, login, screen-corruption

This is what I get in the login screen, it disappears only when I move the mouse and it only happens in the login screen.

[image: screen corruption]

This is Ubuntu 12. 04 running over an Intel desktop board DG31PR and I'm using the onboard video.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do a check on you VGA cable.

Comment: >.< facepalm here, actually it looked well connected when i checked but regardless of that i adjusted it even more and that resolved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is embarrassing, it was just a slightly loose cable as suggested by Mitch, but anyway this could help someone with the same problem to realize that maybe it is not a driver/system/configuration problem.